# Number of repetitions before collision (linked to but not exactly Birthday Problem)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, birthday

There are $M$ persons in a room, and each one has chosen a random integer in $[1, N]$ (here $M$ much smaller than $N$).

Now I **repeat the experience of randomly choosing a number in $[1, N]$** and asking people if I have the same number than the one they have, until I get a collision with someone. Let $Y$ be the random variable "number of attempts to get the first collision".

Note: I won't try a second time with the same number if this number didn't match.

**How to get the expected value $E[Y]$, as a function of $M$ and $N$?**

Note: people don't have to disclose their number to each other, except if there is a collision (then end of the process anyway). The process could go like this:

*"I chose number 7, does anyone have it? No? Let's continue. I chose number 12, does anyone have it? No? Let's continue. I chose number 2, does anyone have it? (Somebody raises its hand). Ok, Y=3."*

---

Example:

$N=365$ bitrthday dates, $M=30$ people in the room.

It is linked to the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), but not exactly the same: in the birthday problem, everyone says its birthday date, and we check if there is a collision between **any pair of people in the room**.
Here only one person (me) is repeating the task of taking random numbers, and asking if there is a collision **between me and one of them**.

Comment: The number of trials until you get a collision will follow a geometric distribution; is that enough of a hint for you to find the expectation?

Comment: @E-A it's close to a geometric distribution but it's not because if number 7 has no collision in the first attempt, we don't try it anymore in the next attempts. For a geometric we need to repeat the random experiment with the same probability of success each time, here it's slightly different.

Comment: Oh yeah I guess I did not understand the setup :P The answer below looks right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability the process lasts beyond the $k^{th}$ stage is $$\left(\frac{N-k}N\right)^M$$
The probability the process lasts exactly $k$ stages is $$\left(\frac{N-k+1}N\right)^M-\left(\frac{N-k}N\right)^M$$
The average number of stages is $$\sum_{k=1}^N k\left[\left(\frac{N-k+1}N\right)^M-\left(\frac{N-k}N\right)^M\right]=\sum_{k=0}^N\left(\frac{N-k}N\right)^M\\=\frac1{N^M}\sum_{k=1}^Nk^M\approx\frac N{M+1}+\frac12$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain the first assertion? Remark: if a number doesn't match, we won't try the same number in further attempts, so it's not a geometric distribution.

Comment: M users must each avoid your $k$ choices.  The chance of any one doing so is $(N-k)/N$.  Different users make independent choices, so you multiply the probabilities together to get the $M$th power.

Comment: Thanks. So did you assume I dont retry a number that has not worked before?

Comment: Yes, I did.  I haven't worked out the odds if you pick numbers completely at random.

Comment: If numbers are picked totally at random (i.e. we might retry a number that has failed before), then it's a geometric distribution with p=M/N. Them the expected value is N/M.

Comment: Or maybe for this to be true we need to replace M by M' the number of *distinct* values chosen by the M people.